# RXJS takeUntil and switchMap with a timer seems not to complete inner timer

Tags: typescript, rxjs

I have the following code:

```
  private takeControlTaskRunning$ = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);

  private initTakeControlTask() {
    this.takeControlTaskRunning$
      .pipe(
        takeUntil(this.dependencies.destroyed$),
        switchMap((isRunning) => {
          if (!isRunning) {
            return of(false);
          }
          return timer(0, this.updatePeriodMilliseconds).pipe(
            takeUntil(this.dependencies.destroyed$), <--- Why is this needed?
            map(() => {
              return true;
            })
          );
        }),
        filter((isRunning) => isRunning === true),
      )
      .subscribe(async () => {
        await this.syncVideo();
      });
  }

  public takeControl() {
    this.takeControlTaskRunning$.next(true);
  }

  public stopControl() {
    this.takeControlTaskRunning$.next(false);
  }
```

When I run this in an fakeAsync test,

```
  describe('takeControl', () => {
    it('runs the update task periodically', fakeAsync(async () => {
      // Given an controller instance
      const { controller, dependencies } = await create();

      // When takeControl is called
      await controller.takeControl();
      // And some time passes
      jasmine.clock().tick(1);

      // Then the update task should be running
      expect(
        dependencies.updateSync as jasmine.Spy
      ).toHaveBeenCalle();

      destroyed$.next();
      flush();
    }));
  });
```

I get the following error:

```
Error: 1 periodic timer(s) still in the queue.
```

Adding an inner takeUntil seems to fix it, but I don't understand why it is required. As far as I understand the outer takeUntil should complete the observable, and the switchMap should complete the inner timer, why is this not the case?

Comment: `Decoded Frontend` gives more explanation of why you should keep `takeUntil()` operator as the last operator

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is order of operators. As a general rule of thumb `takeUntil()` should always be the last operator in a chain.

What happens in your case is that `this.takeControlTaskRunning$` emits which is projected using `switchMap` into `timer()`. But when `takeUntil()` emits `complete` notification it's stopped by `switchMap` that still waits for its inner Observable (`timer()` in this case) to complete.

If you put `takeUntil()` after `switchMap()` the `complete` notification will reach the observer which triggers unsubscription even when the inner Observable in `switchMap()` is still pending and will be unsubscribed immediatelly.

Comment: that was so helpful! Thank you very much

Comment: I like that rule of thumb of putting takeUntil as the last operator in a chain. But what about when there is a filter operation? The reason I use to put it in the top is that I was concerned that a fitler would prevent the takeUntil from running, but probably is a misunderstanding from my side on how things get chained. What do you think?

Comment: `takeUntil()` won't interfere with `filter()` because it passes through all notifications (`next`, `complete` and `error`) and only listens to its inner Observable that you pass as a parameter and then eventually emits `complete`. So `takeUntil()` itself doesn't handle `next` notification passing through.